# Setting jqplot minimum bar height

Tags: jqplot

I want to set a minimum height on a stacked bar so that it always shows no matter how small the value.

Example:

If the stacked values are relatively close, the bars show no problem:

http://i41.tinypic.com/b88rc6.png

But if the values differ by a lot, then the smaller bar is not visible on the graph:

http://i40.tinypic.com/15rxwz6.png

I tried reading through the docs but didn't find any options for this. Help is appreciated!

Comment: I think to achieve this you have to manipulate the code inside the barrenderer to have a minimum height

Comment: I could maybe try this. If you have any pointers to which files or piece of code that needs to be modified please let me know.

Comment: but it will not be logical because then you have to manipulate yaxis ticks. i think you should manipulate the yaxis min and max to make your smaller bars visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assing the smaller values to an other yaxis, so the graph will show 2 different yaxes, the first with a big interval, the second with an interval that permits to show correctly the smaller values (if you want to show the difference between the two kind of data, you could use min and max on the smaller yaxis).

```
axes: { [...], yaxes: { -big values-  }, y2axes: { -small values-, min: -10, max: 10 }}
```

Don't know if that answer would be useful to you.